# Copy files through specific Lan card of the source server

Tags: networking, ssis, batch-file, copy-paste, lan

I want to copy backup from one server to another on daily bases. I would like to create any Script or SSIS package to do so. I cannot run that script from the destination server.

The source server has two LAN cards connected to the network with different IPs (obviously). One IP is used by the application and I want to use the other IP to copy the backup so that it may not affect the application performance.

Could you please guide me that how will I specy the specific IP of the source server through which i can copy the data to the destination server? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll call the two NICs Primary and Secondary.  Primary is your NIC for your application.  Secondary is your management NIC.

One approach you can use is to configure two DNS names for your host, one per IP address, with at least two IP addresses, one on each NIC.  With the name that resolves to the IP address which is on the Secondary NIC (secondary.example.com), would this work for you?

```
strarc64 -c -mf backup.bin \\secondary.example.com\c$\path\to\backup
```

You can get strarc/strarc64 from [here](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/), and its usage [here](http://www.ltr-data.se/files/strarc.txt)